# JSX in Typescript without React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I tried to use typescript with jsx without react. and it doesn't work.
I always put a `"jsx": "preserve"` in tsconfig.json.
But i dont understand what i have to do next.and when i am compiling .tsx file webpack throws an error

`ERROR in ./core/Navbar.tsx`
`Module parse failed: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/framework/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js!/home/ubuntu/Desktop/framework/core/Navbar.tsx Unexpected token (9:15)`

`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`
i read the documentation but i dont understand how to use global jsx module in project.
is it possible to use typescript + jsx  without react?

[image]
my App.tsx class

[[image: my App.tsx class[2]]

error when webpack compile file
[image: console error]

Comment: Here I found simple implementation of function React.createElement: https://yetawf.com/BlogEntry/Title/TypeScript%20and%20JSX%20without%20React/?BlogEntry=1034

Answer (score 17):

Use tsconfig `reactNamespace` option:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "reactNamespace": "JSX",
  }
}
```

Define the `JSX` namespace with a `createElement` function:

```
// index.tsx
export const JSX = {
  createElement(name: string, props: { [id: string]: string }, ...content: string[]) {
    props = props || {};
    const propsstr = Object.keys(props)
      .map(key => {
        const value = props[key];
        if (key === "className") return `class=${value}`;
        else return `${key}=${value}`;
      })
      .join(" ");
      return `<${name} ${propsstr}> ${content.join("")}</${name}>`;
  },
};

export default JSX;
```

declare the types

```
// external.d.ts
declare module JSX {
  type Element = string;
  interface IntrinsicElements {
    [elemName: string]: any;
  }
}
```

Usage example

```
import JSX from "./index";

function Hello(name: string) {
    return (
        <div className="asd">
            Hello {name}
            <div> Hello Nested </div>
            <div> Hello Nested 2</div>
        </div>
    );
}

function log(html: string) {
    console.log(html);
}

log(Hello("World"));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use jsx: prevserve, it means that the Typescript compiler will output .jsx files rather than compiling it down to .js, as a result, you will need something like Babel to transpile your jsx eventually since your browser can't run jsx files.

To be honest, I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you should either use jsx: react, or jsx: preserve + transpiler

Comment: thanx for ur answer. i understand) so i need to transpile my jsx after tsx compilation to jsx. but how can i do that? i am using webpack. and what loaders i need? and how to run jsx transpiler after ts-loader?

Comment: can u show a valid webpack config for compiling typscript + jsx?

Comment: i think i have to chain loaders ts-loader!babel right?

Comment: yes, you need to chain loaders, but it would be babel-loader!ts-loader, you want the output of ts compiler r into babel

Comment: but is there a reason you want to use babel? Typescript compiler can compile .tsx into .js directly if you use 'jsx: react'

Comment: I don't want to use react in project.

Comment: I chained  loaders how u said but I got an error.it is like a babel loader doesn't understand a public static..so I will attach image of error later

Comment: you don't have to use react, having 'jsx: react' in your tsconfig simply tells ts compiler to compile tsx/jsx to js - it doesnt enforce you to use react, try it and let us know

Comment: i have a file App.tsx and i wrote "jsx":"react" in config. when webpack compiles file it throws an error 
`(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'React'.`

Comment: what error do you get if you use babel-loader!ts-loader? make sure you install babel-preset-react, and have .babelrc like this here https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/

Comment: yes i did all by ur instructions. but in didnt worked.

Comment: It throws an error like this again `(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'React'.`

Comment: i dont understand what i have to do. i dont want use react. i want use jsx natively. why this is a problem(((

Comment: if you use babel-loader together with ts-loader then you want to have JSX: preserve; not react

Answer (score 1):

Look at Stefan Baumgartners [blog entry "JSX is syntactic sugar"](https://fettblog.eu/jsx-syntactic-sugar/). It explains how to convert JSX to DOM elements at runtime using clean, easily readable code.